# 2A223J fixed capacitor immediately shows OL on resistance test

Tags: capacitor, testing

I have a 2A223J fixed capacitor. When set in resistance mode, I'm showing OL when tester leads are touching each (separate) capacitor lead.

I just tested a new .22uF capacitor and i saw resistance rise steadily till it reached OL. A little different from the suspect 2A223J.

Is the 2A223J borked?

Comment: Both capacitors read open, this is correct. The rate isn't a reliable measure because you don't know what current the resistance range is testing with, nor how fast it actually performs the reading.  223 is however 22nF, not 220; you seem to have misread it.  Presuming you mean to replace it or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resistances tend to be measured with limited current.  If the current is near constant, voltage (and thus displayed resistance) will rise linearly in time, at a rate inversely proportional to the capacitance.  The inverse of the Ohms per second rise rate will be an approximation of the capacitance.

So finding a measuring range where the rise from 0 Ohm to outside the measuring range takes a few seconds will give you a good estimate of the capacitance you are dealing with.

As long as the capacitor has no leak, the reading *will* always run off the measuring range eventually, apparently indicated by "OL" by your meter.

To repeat the measurement, you usually need to turn the capacitor around (it starts with "negative" resistance then).  Or discharge it in some other manner.